# Hide element by class (only Javascript, no Jquery)

Tags: javascript, onclick

I would like to hide Elements by class name. I found a working example that runs outside of a function. However, when I use onClick it doesn't seem to work anymore.
Please take a look at the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/SkfDz/9/
Can anyone please help me?

HTML:

```
<input class="" name="options" id="opt1" type="radio" onClick="hideToday()"/><label for="opt1">Hide today</label>
<input class="" name="options" id="opt1" type="radio" onClick="hideToday()"/><label for="opt1">Hide today</label>

<div class="today">TODAY</div>
<div class="today">TODAY</div>
<div class="today">TODAY</div>

<div class="tomorrow">TOMORROW</div>
```

Script:

```
function hideToday() {
    var todayElements = document.getElementsByClassName('today'), i;
    for (i = 0; i < todayElements.length; i += 1) {
    todayElements[i].style.display = 'none';
    };
};

var tomorrowElements = document.getElementsByClassName('tomorrow'), i;
for (i = 0; i < tomorrowElements.length; i += 1) {
    tomorrowElements[i].style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: [You could do this more simply and quickly with CSS.](http://jsfiddle.net/XtM4C/)

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't work in jsfiddle is that your `hideToday` function is out of scope. I don't know which scope the script in jsfiddle exists, but it seems it isn't global.

If you put the same code in a webpage and view it, it works as expected:

```
<html>
<body>
    <input class="" name="options" id="opt1" type="radio" onClick="hideToday()"/><label for="opt1">Hide today</label>
    <input class="" name="options" id="opt1" type="radio" onClick="hideToday()"/><label for="opt1">Hide today</label>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="today">TODAY</div>
    <div class="today">TODAY</div>
    <div class="today">TODAY</div>
    <br>
    <div class="tomorrow">TOMORROW</div>
    <script>
        function hideToday() {
            var todayElements = document.getElementsByClassName('today'), i;
            for (i = 0; i < todayElements.length; i += 1) {
            todayElements[i].style.display = 'none';
            };
        };

        var appBanners = document.getElementsByClassName('tomorrow'), i;
        for (i = 0; i < appBanners.length; i += 1) {
            appBanners[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can fix your fiddle by exporting `hideToday` onto `window`:

```
window["hideToday"] = hideToday;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SkfDz/16/

Comment: The jsfiddle controls allow you to tell it to wrap the code typed in the lower left quadrant in a window "load" handler. It's also possible to tell it not to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the onClick that way, which is a bad idea, you need to put your javascript in you `Head`, so you can make your fiddle work just by changing the second select box on top left to `No wrap - in <head>` But it would be better to not use inline javascript and put event handling in external file too.